# Internal Server Error when docker container is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I follow the instructions here:
http://glynjackson.org/weblog/tutorial-deploying-django-app-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-docker/
on how to deploy a very basic django app in docker container to Elastic Beanstalk.
Everything went smoothly. When I check the container locally it works perfectly (showing the standart `Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.` text). It is uploaded to EB correctly. But when I open the page, it reports 'Internal server error'. Why is it so?

the content of `Dockerrun.aws.json`:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Logging": "/var/eb_log"
 }
```

the content of `Dockerfile`  is just copied from Glyn's git rep:
https://github.com/glynjackson/django-docker-template/blob/master/Dockerfile

Here  are the few lines of the content of EB logs:
(The full log is here: https://gist.github.com/chapkovski/25ee9099a0b7e23a6aacb477bc747f82)

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2017/10/13 15:33:19 [warn] 24970#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" 
in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-
proxy.conf:11
2017/10/13 15:33:19 [warn] 24976#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html"     in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
2017/10/13 15:33:20 [warn] 25127#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
2017/10/13 15:33:21 [warn] 25135#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some detail from the `/var/eb_log` you mention near the start of your question.

Comment: just added, sorry

Comment: No probs.  Getting an 'internal server error' here means that Nginx is passing through ok, and your django application is throwing a 500 error.  If you can access the gunicorn logs, that will help debug, or you can run your app with `Debug=True` if it's not yet public facing.

Comment: the weird thing is DEBUG=True in settings.